# Want to use a specific version of python in linux

Tags: python, python-2.7

Respected users,
While post processing data with the help of a script which was originally written in python not in python3.x. So now while I am running it it gives too many error. How I can i use the older version of python I have both installed 2.7 as well as 3.8.3. It would be very helpful if somebody gives an idea.

Comment: load ```python2.7```

Comment: Consider creating a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) based on the desired interpreter.

Comment: what is the distro and version of your linux? did you manually install python2.7 or was it pre-installed?

Comment: run it like this : python2.7 your script_name

Comment: The best option is the use a virtual environment with Python version set to Python 2.

Comment: which system/os are you running? if linux, just use python for python2 and python3 for python3. If it is windows, you've to set some variables, mostly the path (read https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#configuring-python and https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#configuring-python).